# Low/mid/high 230 V fan control with Raspberry Pi

Tags: power, motor, ac, raspberry-pi

I have 230 VAC, 300 W fan, a SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay, and a Raspberry Pi.

What other equipment would I need to control the 230 VAC fan with a Raspberry Pi?

I want to go 0/1 with relay, and in mode:1 be able to control low/mid/high fan speed.

[image]

Comment: you need a triac (and snubber) and a zero crossing detector for syncing the waveform. or i guess for a fan you could simply use a zero-crossing integrated SSR and skip entire half-cycles to achieve speeds, so long as the kick noise isn't bothersome.

Comment: low mid high selection by an external knob or by raspberry pi?

Comment: Correct me when necessary,
So it goes like Raspberry Pi -> OptoCoupler -> ZeroCrossing Detector -> Triac -> Engine

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWn5PD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitors should be the type used for fans speed controllers (X2 rating) and of appropriate capacitance, the numbers I used are guesses. if you have a four position 
knob type speed controller you probably already have theses capacitors.

Turing on relay 1 puts C1 in series with the mains for slow speed, turning on relay 2 puts C2 in series for medium speed, turning on both connects L1 directly for full speed.

for the top realy you could use the relay module you have for the bottom relay you need a relay with two switches, (or you could use two more of the same module both connected to the same raspberry pi output)

Comment: That is fantastic, exactly as i remember from some AirConditioning Units.
Listen Jasen, you wrote NANOFarads. Shoud not that be MICROFarads?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do all of the above features with simply an opto-isolated solid-state relay designed for inductive loads. You simply control the SSR with one of the Pi's GPIO's.

This arrangement simplifies the design to one solid-state part that provides the isolation, control, and reliability over EM relay. Plus, you have precise, modulated speed control that can be manipulated via software in the Pi (PWM) that you don't get with EM relay solutions (fixed, discreet speeds).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcnash.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure you can use PWM for AC motor? Usually the switches switch in different capacitors to control the speed. Would you please explain how and why your answer will work? Also this does not answer the question how to do it with the components given but suggests another way.

Comment: Yes you can do it. I've done this personally. You just use an ultra low switching frequency (~10Hz). Switching in an out capacitors is the old, "caveman" way to do it. It's still done that way because its ultra-simplicity - you don't need a PCB or a controller. Very similar to cheap table fans (however, they usually switch in and out different coils not caps). Sure, if the requirement is to use all the components stated, then the EM relay gets put in series with the SSR - this would be redundant considering the SSR intrinsically does this. Plus, you need to use another GPIO pin this way.

Comment: Fine, but how should the original speed setting be removed then? Left at full speed, while driving mains with PWM? What other changes or modifications are needed before you can PWM it?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no original speed setting. If this fan already has integrated speeds, then the fan gets set to the highest (full) speed. The SSR modulates it -100% DC for high; 70% DC for medium; 30% DC for low; 0% for off. The small caveat, an RC snubber may be required across the SSR output terminals to prevent latch-up. But an SSR properly designed for reactive loads shouldn't need that.